# Why does this thumbnail generation code throw OutOfMemoryException on large files?

Tags: c#, graphics, thumbnails, out-of-memory

This code works great for generating thumbnails, but when given a very large (100MB+) TIFF file, it throws OutOfMemoryExceptions. When I do it manually in Paint.NET on the same machine, it works fine.  How can I improve this code to stop throwing on very large files?

In this case I'm loading a 721MB TIF on a machine with 8GB RAM. The Task Manager shows 2GB used so something is preventing it from *using* all that memory. Specifically it throws when I load the Image to calculate the size of the original. What gives?

```
/// <summary>Creates a thumbnail of a given image.</summary>
/// <param name="inFile">Fully qualified path to file to create a thumbnail of</param>
/// <param name="outFile">Fully qualified path to created thumbnail</param>
/// <param name="x">Width of thumbnail</param>
/// <returns>flag; result = is success</returns>
public static bool CreateThumbnail(string inFile, string outFile, int x)
{
  // Mathematically determine Y dimension
  int y;
  using (Image img = Image.FromFile(inFile)) // Exception thrown
      y = (int)((double)img.Height * ((double)x / (double)img.Width));

  // Make thumbnail     
  using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(inFile)) 
    using (Bitmap thumb = new Bitmap((Image)bmp, new Size(x, y))) 
      using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(thumb)) {
        g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.High;
        g.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
        ImageCodecInfo codec = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders()[1];
        EncoderParameters ep2 = new EncoderParameters(1);
        ep2.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, 100L);
        g.DrawImage(bmp, new Rectangle(0,0,thumb.Width, thumb.Height));
        try {
          thumb.Save(outFile, codec, ep2);
          return true; }
        catch { return false; }
      }
}
```

Comment: does this happen with every image of this size or just particular instances? I know I get OOM from GDI for certain images regardless of size and it usually ends up that I am not jumping through the right GDI hoops for the stream at hand.

Comment: Every very large image, JPG or TIF. Mostly TIFs just because that's most of my "imagebase". Works great for files under 100MB or so, and some of my TIFs go into the GBs.

Comment: tsilb: I snipped the validation code (since it didn't touch the file) and squeezed the formatting to make the code block less intimidating.  Please roll back if you think these changes took out anything important.

Comment: Can you track down which bit causes the OOM exception -- e.g. loading from inFile, creating the new Bitmap from the existing one, doing the DrawImage, performing the Save?

Comment: Yep, accidentally edited that part out - re-added "exception thrown" comment (loads image to calculate the Y dimension) - also a bit of refactoring I noticed I could do while reexamining the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My wild guess is that, you are running it as a 32-bit application. Which limits your app's memory usage to a theoretical 2 GB, which is really more like 1.5 GB empirically.

Comment: Occurs both in Prod in a .NET 4.0 app pool, IIS 6, x64 OS; and in debug on an x64 machine with vs2010 rc x64... not sure how else to verify that...

Comment: If you are really running the process in an Windows x64 env, you can verify whether the app is running as x86 by opening your task manager and locating your app's process. If it has no *32, my wild guess is wrong.

Comment: Dang, you're right. Looks like 64-bit can be done in VS but it makes debugging near impossible.  How about a way to make it work from IIS?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with [FastImageGDIPlus](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/gdi32/GdipLoadImage.html?diff=y). It has worked well for me - but I've never tried loading a 721 MB file.